# What to do if a column overlaps into another column in a dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataset

so I have a csv file which is of the form -

```
No.         Name           Money
1          Tom Cat           100
2          Dan Man           200
3          Marie             Claw300
4          Catherine K.      400
```

I need to detect if the some part of my second column data is in my third column. Is there a way in python to do this efficiently?

Also, this is a made up example the whole dataset contains many cases like this and it is not a one-off incident.

Edit - 
Expected output

```
No.         Name           Money
1          Tom Cat           100
2          Dan Man           200
3          Marie Claw        300
4          Catherine K.      400
```

Comment: I assume you didn't create this CSV? If you did, you need to tackle the problem there

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```py
>>> data = """No.         Name           Money
... 1          Tom Cat           100
... 2          Dan Man           200
... 3          Marie             Claw300
... 4          Catherine K.      400"""
```

---

Convert the `dtype` of Money column to numeric type and coerce errors to get `NaN` values when they are not numbers.

```py
>>> df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), header=None, skiprows=1, delimiter=r'\s\s+', engine='python', names=["No", "Name", "Money"])
>>> df
   No          Name    Money
0   1       Tom Cat      100
1   2       Dan Man      200
2   3         Marie  Claw300
3   4  Catherine K.      400
```

---

```py
>>> df.Money = pd.to_numeric(df.Money, errors="coerce")
>>> df
   No          Name  Money
0   1       Tom Cat  100.0
1   2       Dan Man  200.0
2   3         Marie    NaN
3   4  Catherine K.  400.0
```

**EDIT**

```py
>>> df.Name = df.Name.str.cat(df.Money.str.extract(r'(\D+)').fillna(''))
>>> df.Money = df.Money.str.extract(r'(\d+)')
>>> df
   No          Name Money
0   1       Tom Cat   100
1   2       Dan Man   200
2   3     MarieClaw   300
3   4  Catherine K.   400
```

Comment: This seems correct. But is there a way to retain 300 and the name 'Marie Claw'. I updated the question with expected output. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the correct datatype for the column Money is numeric. This will subset your df and return only the rows with wrong data:

```
df[df.applymap(np.isreal)['Money'] == False]
```